How do I repair a damaged wood floor panel?
A section of wooden floor panel (Barlinek) has been damaged by a heavy object being dropped, creating a roughly rectangular depression with two of the sides of this depression being an actual crack in the top veneer of the panel. How can this be repaired without the panel being replaced (replacement is not a viable option)?
One method I have read about is introducing some water into the cracked sides and then heating with a protective cloth and iron so that, presumably, the water expands/steams and pushes the depressed part back up level with the rest of the floor. Thoughts?


It would be best if trying something to test in a hidden area first(under a sofa,closet).  Do not know the finish so heat/moisture might damaged it, making it worst looking.  Could think about getting a nice area carpet/mat, since I doubt any repair will make look like new/not damaged, if it is cracked.

A pic of the damage rather than a link to the flooring is prefered here.

It may depend whether or not it's is real hardwood; your product appears to be engineered.  If it was real hardwood, I have successfully used the steam method to get impact depressions mostly out of a butcher block countertop.  But engineered has a plywood and/or HDF substrate, which may behave differently.

The water/iron/steam method works on solid wood, not on broken-surface veneer over particleboard or fiberboard. The particleboard and fiberboard absorb water and expand much more drastically than regular wood, and you'll get a raised bubble at the damaged surface that you won't be able to get rid of or squish back down.
However, a Barlinek link seems to indicate that this type of floor is layers of real wood all the way down, not a veneer over particleboard or fiberboard:

From the link:

SURFACE LAYER – selected sawn cut European oak, ash wood, oiled or lacquered.
MIDDLE AND BOTTOM LAYER – structure made of coniferous wood.

So the steam method might work to raise the top layer wood fibers without causing the swelling of the underlayers.
The finish isn't going to be perfect, though, and may very well be damaged by the steaming process. I have only steamed dents out of wood before it went to the finishing room at my old cabinet shop job. I have usually had to sand the wood after steaming to remove the look of the dent and the raised wood fibers that the steaming lifted.
You may need to sand and refinish the portion of wood you steamed. Experimentation on a spare piece of the flooring if available would be a good ides.

Ask the manufacturer or store for a "sample" of an identical piece, to practice on.
Look on youtube and Amazon for laminate repair kits.  There are all kinds ... they mostly involve doing as little as possible to hide the damage, and I think that's most appropriate for you.   Use your sample piece to practice with each one.
Here's a technique you could try, if your practice shows you can achieve it.  You have more than a surface scratch, so this technique eliminates the sharp ridge, allowing you to use available patch kits at what they are best at: Hiding surface damage.


With a razor, carefully cut out a triangular chip from the surface as shown in the photo.  Cut along the lines at an angle towards the center.  The surface must remain intact.
Fill the deep side of the divot with filler and push the chip in, gently so it's flush all around.  Filler should ooze out but don't push it beyond flush.  Carefully wipe off excess filler without pushing the chip in any more.
Leave it to dry, then carefully wipe away dried-on excess filler and use a repair kit according to its instructions.  At this stage all you are doing is color-matching a small scratch.   Practice on your piece first!

